# Laravel middleware before the routes are registered

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware

I am developing a Laravel application. Now, I am trying to create a middleware that is checked before any routes are registered. Logically, this is what I am trying to do. I have a list of routes saved in the database. Imaging, there is a model called Redirection for it. In the middleware, I want to check, if the requested path falls into one of the redirections in the database, I will redirect to a different path. Now, I created a middleware called RedirectMiddleware. Then I registered it in the kernel class like this,

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            RedirectMiddleware::class,
        ],
        'api' => [
            //other stuff
        ],
    ];
```

The problem is that when I access the route that does not exist, it renders the 404 error page without going through the middleware first. How can I create/ register a middleware which is called before any routes are registered? Or what could be the better approach to achieve what I want to achieve instead of using middleware?

Comment: The route needs to exist in order for you to validate the path.

Comment: Consider a [fallback route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#fallback-routes)?

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel the HTTP Kernel handles the middleware registration. But to register it you have to enter the configuration as you have. In the registration in picks up the desired configuration from the App\Http\Kernel.php. In there, we need to pay attention to our namespace. Laravel only reads what is in the App\Http namespace. When you call your middleware, you are attempting to reference it in relativity as if it is within the current namespace.

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            RedirectMiddleware::class,
        ],
        'api' => [
            //other stuff
        ],
    ];
```

What you need to be doing is referencing it directly. To do this you need to escape the namespace and give the path. Like so...

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
             // Your other middlewares
             \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectMiddleware::class,
        ],
        'api' => [
            //other stuff
        ],
    ];
```

This should solve your issue. If not, let me know and post your middleware so we can see what exactly you are doing.

-- Current Laravel Docs 07/19/2019 :: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#registering-middleware